# Are homeomorphic differentiable manifolds actually diffeomorphic?

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $M$ and $N$ be two n-dimensional smooth manifolds.Suppose their underlying topological spaces are homeomorphic through $f$. Does $f$ automatically become a diffeomorphism with respect to the given smooth structures? If not, can I adjust any of the smooth structures to make $f$ a diffeomorphism? What if I restrict the manifolds to be embedded manifolds in Euclidean space $\mathbb{E}^n$ with endowed topology and smooth structure?

Comment: You might find this interesting: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffeomorphism#Homeomorphism_and_diffeomorphism

Comment: In high dimensions, adjustment may not be possible. A summary of what is currently known can be found in this [answer](http://mathoverflow.net/a/97019/33248) for a related question on MO.

Comment: The answer is no. Take exotic 7-spheres.

Comment: @BrianFitzpatrick : If X,Y are homeomorphic but not diffeomorphic, what properties distinguish them?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Let $M=N=\mathbb R$, endowed with its usual structure of a smooth manifold, and let$f:M\to N$ be the map such that $f(x)=x^3$. This is a homeomorphism but not a diffeo!

Now, if $f:M\to N$ is a homeomorphism of smooth manifolds, you can always «adjust» the smooth structures so that $f$ becomes a diffeo: indeed, you should be able to prove the following:

> if $M$ is a smooth manifold, $N$ a *topological space* and $f:M\to N$ a homeomorphism, then there is a structure of smooth manifold on $N$ such that $f$ becomes a diffeomorphism.

Comment: In your second and third paragraphs, are you still assuming that $M = N = \mathbb{R}$ or are you now allowing them to be arbitrary smooth manifolds, as in the OP?

Answer (score 6):

In higher dimensions there exist [exotic spheres](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exotic_sphere) which are smooth manifolds that are homeomorphic *but not diffeomorphic* to the $n$-sphere.

This gives a negative answer to your first question.

If by "adjust any of the smooth structure" means throw away the smooth structure 
on one of the manifolds and install a new unrelated one, then obviously you can use $f$ to transfer the smooth structure of one manifold to another¸ and $f$ then trivially becomes diffeomorphism. But arguably the manifold whose structure you "adjusted" wont't be the same *smooth manifold* anymore.

If I'm understanding things correctly, the exotic spheres can even be embedded smoothly in $\mathbb R^m$ for sufficiently large $m$.

Comment: Yes, you are understanding things correctly: Whitney proved that any  connected (Hausdorff and second countable, of course)  differential manifold of dimension $n$ can be embedded smoothly into $\mathbb R^{2n}$ .

Comment: @ Georeges Elencwajg : If M,X are homeomorphic but not diffeomorphic, what properties does X have that M does not?