# Diffeomorphisms imply bijections between the set of smooth functions?

Tags: smooth-manifolds, smooth-functions, diffeomorphism

This interesting [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3265743/700775) raised a question in my mind:

Suppose that $M$ and $N$ are smooth manifolds and $f:$ $M \rightarrow N$ is a diffeomorphism. Can we conclude that $C^{\infty} (M)$ and $C^{\infty} (N)$ are isomorphic? In other words, is there a one to one correspondence between smooth functions on the two smooth manifolds? ($C^{\infty} (M)$ denotes the set of smooth functions from $M$ to $\mathbf{R}$).

Thanks

Comment: Yes. This follows from the fact that $M \mapsto C^\infty(M)$ is a contravariant functor.

Comment: The function\begin{align}C^\infty(N)&\to C^\infty(M)\\\phi&\mapsto \phi\circ f \end{align}is invertible (the function\begin{align}C^\infty(M)&\to C^\infty(N)\\\psi&\mapsto \psi\circ f^{-1} \end{align}is its inverse). Does this answer your question?

Comment: @MarkSaving: Thanks. So this follows from the fact that there is a contravariant functor from Top (category of topological spaces) to Set.

Comment: @Filippo: Yes, thanks very much for your answer. That was exactly what I was looking for.